# How to make javascript work for every image in the while loop?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I made a while loop that displays pictures and i want the user to be able to zoom in each of the pictures but it only works for the first image
The img is in the while loop and the script is on the end of my code outside the while loop.

```
<img id="zoom" src="img/<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?> " data-zoom-image="img/<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?> "/>

<script>
     $("#zoom").elevateZoom({scrollZoom : true});  
 </script>
```

Comment: OK, I'll be the one to ask ... which `while` loop? a while loop in PHP? anyway ... that aside, you'll end up with non-unique ID's in your HTML, which makes it invalid

Comment: Change  id="zoom" to  class="zoom" and change $("#zoom").elevateZoom to $(".zoom").elevateZoom

Comment: @Grumpy - you do know that both will work identically ... jquery (also querySelectorAll) actually will get all elements with one id :p so, while your comment is 100% valid, it won't change how the code runs

Comment: They dont work identical, now it goes by class (multiple selectors ) instead of id ( single selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you're targetting an unique id that's not actually unique, so I'd remove that id and target the `[data-zoom-image]` instead.

```php
<?php while($your_condition) ?>

  <img src="img/<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?> " data-zoom-image="img/<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?> "/>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<script>
  $("[data-zoom-image]").elevateZoom({scrollZoom : true});  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but now i added this script that shows only 8 pictures and then when you click the 'load more' it shows 4 more pictures and depends on how many times you press it, it shows more and more pictures and the zoom does not work, This is the script and the button <a class="btn2 loading-more"> <i class="icon_loading"></i> Load More </a> <script> $(".col").slice(0, 8).show() $(".btn2").on("click", function(){ $(".col:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown() if ($(".col:hidden").length == 0) { $(".btn2").fadeOut('slow') } }) </script>

Comment: @jimmys No problem. After clicking, you could try resetting it and adding it again, like: `$('.zoomContainer').remove(); $("[data-zoom-image]").elevateZoom({scrollZoom : true});`

Comment: i already tried that but it does not work. Do you know any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the below,

```
<img id="zoom" src="img/<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?> " data-zoom-image="img/<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?> "/>
<script>
  $("[data-zoom-image^=img]").each(function(){$(this).elevateZoom({scrollZoom : true});});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but now i added this script that shows only 8 pictures and then when you click the 'load more' it shows 4 more pictures and depends on how many times you press it, it shows more and more pictures and the zoom does not work, This is the script and the button <a class="btn2 loading-more"> <i class="icon_loading"></i> Load More </a> <script> $(".col").slice(0, 8).show() $(".btn2").on("click", function(){ $(".col:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown() if ($(".col:hidden").length == 0) { $(".btn2").fadeOut('slow') } }) </script>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php while($your_condition) ?>

  <img src="img/<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?> " class="zoom_image" data-zoom-image="img/<?php echo $rows['picture']; ?> "/>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<script>
  $(".zoom_image").elevateZoom({scrollZoom : true});  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but now i added this script that shows only 8 pictures and then when you click the 'load more' it shows 4 more pictures and depends on how many times you press it, it shows more and more pictures and the zoom does not work, This is the script and the button <a class="btn2 loading-more"> <i class="icon_loading"></i> Load More </a> <script> $(".col").slice(0, 8).show() $(".btn2").on("click", function(){ $(".col:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown() if ($(".col:hidden").length == 0) { $(".btn2").fadeOut('slow') } }) </script>